# When will bindElement call the real service?

Tags: sapui5

Main.view.xml:

```
<ObjectHeader
    id="objectHeader"
    title="{name}"
    intro="{id}">
    <headerContainer>
        <IconTabBar
            id="tabBar"
            items="{
                path: 'assigned',
                parameters: {expand: 'b, c'} 
            }"
            select="onTabBarSelect">
        </IconTabBar>       
    </headerContainer>
</ObjectHeader>
```

Main.controller.js

```
onMasterSelectionChange : function (sPath) {
    var oSource = oEvent.getParameter("listItem") || oEvent.getSource(),
    // sPath = "/ASet('d')"
    sPath = oSource.getBindingContext().getPath(),
    oObjectHeader = this.byId("objectHeader");

    oObjectHeader.bindElement(sPath);
    this._oModel.attachEventOnce("requestCompleted", function(oEvent) {
        var oTabBar =  this.byId("TabBar");
        oFirstListItem = oTabBar.getItems()[0],
        sObjectId = oFirstListItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("id"),
        sDPath = "/DSet('" + sObjectId + "')";

        this._getControls(sDPath);
    }, this);
}
```

I found a strange behavior: when I change the master list selection, sometimes Network will show a "/ASet/assigned" call, but sometimes there will be no call, which cause `requestCompleted` not fired.

According to: [SAPUI5 - bindElement doesn't work the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074712/sapui5-bindelement-doesnt-work-the-second-time),

> If you call bindElement with the same path twice, the second time won't actually trigger a new call to get new data, since the path didn't change.

But I am sure it is different path. Is there any way that can trigger this call?

---

BTW

```
oObjectHeader.bindElement({
    path : sPath,
    events: {
        change : function (oData, test) {
        },
        dataRequested : function (oData) {
        },
        dataReceived: function (oData) {
        }
    }
});
```

`change` can be fired every time I click master list, but `dataRequested` and `dataReceived` is never called.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `ODataContextBinding.prototype.`[`initialize`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.52/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataContextBinding.js#L49) and see what's happening there (especially at `bReloadNeeded `)

Comment: Can you show us how your app is structured and how bindings are done (in addition to the ObjectHeader)? Are you binding a collection to your master with expand to the "detail"s? In that case, it would make sense that no requests are sent afterwards because the data is already cached whatever you select.

Comment: Sorry, how to get `ODataContextBinding` ? And yes, it is a master-detail with `expand`. My aim is load the first master list item, and activate the first icon tab bar when page opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ODataModel has already loaded the data under `sPath` (check in `myODataModel.oData`) it will not load that data again. Therefore `dataRequested`/`dataReceived` will not fire.

But `change` should fire whenever the path changes no matter if data existed or not.

Comment: Yes, it is cached. But there is some logic I want to trigger in after `dataReived`, what should I do?

Comment: Strange thing is, I set a log a `dataRequested/dataReceived`, they never fired.

Comment: Your master probably loaded ALL the data already. Once you select an entry (`onMasterSelectionChange`) you are just binding the detail view against one of these - already loaded - entries. Therefore it will never fire `dataRequested`/`dataReceived`.

Comment: But if I use `var oTabBar =  this.byId("TabBar");
        oFirstListItem = oTabBar.getItems()[0],` in `change`, data is not binded yet...

Comment: May be recursive binding updates happen after the parents change event :/ In general the timing and specificity of SAPUI5 events quite often sucks...

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but you can actually trigger a network call for the `bindElement` by refreshing the binding within its `change` event.

```
this.getView().bindElement({
    path: "model>/" + sContextPath,
    events: {
        change: function (oEvent) {
            // Get the context binding object
            var oContextBinding = oEvent.getSource();

            // Refresh the binding.
            // This triggers a network call.
            oContextBinding.refresh(false);
        }.bind(this)
    }
});
```

Refreshing the binding, triggers the network call. Also, set the `bForceUpdate` flag of the `refresh` to `false` so that it would only update the UI if there is a change in the data as mentioned in the [APIs](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.52.22/#/api/sap.ui.model.Binding/methods/refresh).

Answer (score 0):

I find a work around by replace `bindElement` by `change`&`oModel.read` ...

```
onMasterSelectionChange : function (sPath) {
    var oSource = oEvent.getParameter("listItem") || oEvent.getSource(),
    // sPath = "/ASet('d')"
    sPath = oSource.getBindingContext().getPath(),
    oObjectHeader = this.byId("objectHeader");

    oObjectHeader.bindElement({
        path : sPath,
        events: {
            change : this._onBindingChange.bind(this, sPath)
        }
    })
},

_onBindingChange : function(sPath) {
    this._oModel.read(sPath + "/assigned", {
        urlParameters: {
            "$expand": "b, c"
        },
        success: function(oData) {
            var aAssigmentSet = oData.results,
            oViewModel = this.getModel("viewModel"),
            oTabBar =  this.byId("hazardTabBar");

            oViewModel.setProperty("/aAssigmentSet", aAssigmentSet);
            oTabBar.bindAggregation("items",
                "viewModel>/aAssigmentSet",
                new sap.m.IconTabFilter({
                    key: "{viewModel>id}",
                    tooltip : "{viewModel>id}",
                    text : {
                        parts: [{path: "viewModel>b/name"},
                        {path: "viewModel>c/type"}],
                        formatter : function(name, type) {
                            var sType = type.split(".");
                            return name + " (" + sType[sType.length - 1] + ")"; 
                        }
                    }
                })
            );

            if (oTabBar.getItems().length > 0) {
                var sSelectedTabKey;
                    sSelectedTabKey = oTabBar.getItems()[0].getKey();
                    oTabBar.fireSelect({selectedKey: sSelectedTabKey});
            }
        }.bind(this),
        error: this.errorCallback.bind(this)
    });
},

onTabBarSelect : function(oEvent) {
    var sRiskAssignmentPath = "/AssignmentSet('" + oEvent.getParameter("selectedKey") + "')";

    this._oModel.read(AssignmentSet + "/assignedAssignedControls", {
        ...
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the propper way to achieve this would be to use the invalidate-Method form Odata-Model.

This invalidates all cached entries and forces a new read for the Bindings:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel%23methods/invalidate